# Web Api Spring.Net Configuration

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-web-api2, spring.net

I have a null object reference when I call spring. I use just web api whit nhibernate

UserController

```
namespace Work.WebServices
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();

        public IList<User> GetAll()
        {
            return userManager.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

AbstractDao

```
namespace Work.Dao
{
    public class AbstractDao
    {
        private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        /// <summary>
        /// Session factory for sub-classes.
        /// </summary>
        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            protected get { return sessionFactory; }
            set { sessionFactory = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get's the current active session. Will retrieve session as managed by the 
        /// Open Session In View module if enabled.
        /// </summary>
        protected ISession CurrentSession
        {
            get { return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); }
        }

        public  IList<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class
        {
            ICriteria criteria = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria<T>();
            return criteria.List<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

UserDao

```
namespace Work.Dao
{
    public class UserDao : AbstractDao
    {
    }
}
```

UserManger:It is here that there is the error. It says userDao is null

```
namespace Work.Managers
{
    public class UserManager
    {
        UserDao userDao;
        [Transaction]
        public IList<User> GetAll()
        {           
            IList<User> List = userDao.GetAll<User>();

            return List;
        }
    }
}
```

SpringSetup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"    xmlns:db="http://www.springframework.net/database">
  <!--<object id="Sauce"
          type="Ploeh.Samples.MenuModel.SauceBéarnaise,
          Ploeh.Samples.MenuModel" />-->
  <!-- Database and NHibernate Configuration -->
  <db:provider id="DbProvider"
                   provider="SqlServer-2.0"
                   connectionString="Data Source=PC-PROF\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db_workn;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
  <!-- NHibernate SessionFactory configuration -->
  <object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate21">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="MappingAssemblies">
      <list>
        <value>Work</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
      <dictionary>
        <entry key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"/>
        <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
      </dictionary>
    </property>
    <!-- provides integation with Spring's declarative transaction management features -->
    <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
  </object>

  <!-- gestionnaire de transactions -->
  <object id="transactionManager"
        type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.HibernateTransactionManager, Spring.Data.NHibernate21">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
  </object>

  <!-- Exception translation object post processor -->
  <object type="Spring.Dao.Attributes.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor, Spring.Data"/>

  <!-- Data Access Objects -->
  <object id="userDao" type="Work.Dao.AbstractDao, Work">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
  </object>
</objects>
```

WebConfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Pour plus d’informations sur la configuration de votre application ASP.NET, rendez-vous sur 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <parsers>
      <parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
    </parsers>
    <context>
      <resource uri="~//SpringSetup.xml"/>
    </context>
  </spring>
  <appSettings></appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Set default logging level to DEBUG -->
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>

    <!-- Set logging for Spring.  Logger names in Spring correspond to the namespace -->
    <logger name="Spring">
      <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="Spring.Data">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="NHibernate">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

My libs
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your manager instance with injected dependencies (your DAO):

```
<object id="userManager" type="Work.Managers.UserManager, Work">
  <property name="Dao" ref="userDao"/>
</object>
```

And create an property for you DAO injection:

```
public class UserManager
{
    //UserDao userDao; // <-- Remove this field
    public UserDao Dao { protected get; set; }
}
```

If you are using **MVC** you need to register your controllers to spring too with **singleton as false**:

```
<object name="UserController" type="Work.WebServices.UserController, Work.WebServices" singleton="false">
  <property name="UserManager" ref="userManager"/>
</object>
```

Create the property for injection:

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    //UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
    public UserManager UserManager { private get; set; }
}
```

If you are using **spring 1.3.2** in the Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Add this line:
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(SpringControllerFactory));
}
```

Or in **lastest version** of spring as you can se [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc.html):

```
public class MvcApplication : SpringMvcApplication
{

}
```

Comment: I forgot to put the User Controller class in this post. I just typing it. And in this class, I have to change something? cordially

Comment: I do not use MVC, Web API only

Comment: I have not readed much about integration with web api. I dont know if this is useful http://cravingcode.blogspot.mx/2012/01/wcf-web-api-dependency-injection-using.html